# Unable to upload file in com_swf joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Unable to upload any file using below joomla component.`JJ SWFUpload Component`

There is no change added with this module. But this same module worked fine couple of weeks back. now it is not working. i would like to know the debug step for this module.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/21091

Comment: Hi there, Myself and @George Wilson are the developers of this component. Could you please be a little more specific. Any you getting any errors whilst trying to upload using the component?

Comment: i dont get any errors. that is the reason. i am tooo confuse. no js error in error console. which js file will tell the uploaded file path.(want to just alert.) i am just checking in handler.js

Comment: i verified folder permission Also, when i alert this error code in  this function ==>uploadError . (handler.js). no alerts happened.

Comment: what PHP version are you using and have you ensured you're running the latest version of Joomla?

Comment: PHP Version :    5.3.4  , Joomla: 2.5. @Lodder couple of days/weeks back  worked, but now it is not working. give me a clue. Where i put,which tell target file location. that is after file uploaded

Comment: Have you installed any extensions, preferably plugins since it was working? There might very well be a conflict.

Comment: site developed on for file upload. no more module/comp/pluging.

Comment: I think it's best this is taken to our Forum or e-mail. Do you think you would be able to create a temporary admin account on your site and send the login details to admin@joomjunk.co.uk ?

Comment: This is intranet site. not for public view. i would like to add one more inform here. very rarely we are getting " Upload Error: 303 " this error also. i am using lamp. is there any hidden folder will create. bcoz i will check the folder and file permissions too. but right now i gave full permission for existing folders. no idea for dyanmic temp folder.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes life a little harder. No, there aren't any hidden folders. Have you disabled or enabled any PHP extensions on LAMP recently?

Comment: folder permission only changed. i tried in other system. but it is not loadding instead site automatically going to logged. and asking relogin. if i relogin. menus are vanished.

Comment: Change the folder permissions back to default. folders should be 755 and files should be 644

Comment: once again i uninstalled and installed in my local machine. in my local i can able to upload document. but i when i try 17 MB. system fail to upload. but upload progross showing as completed.

Comment: Even 3mb also not possible.

Comment: It might be due to your `max_upload_size` which will need to be changed in the php.ini file of the server

Comment: What about the apache error_log?  Are you out of disk space?  Or user quota?  Whatever the reason, if you have enough space to write the logs it will be there.

Comment: i have noticed, module working fine. but when we getting some error like " File is too big " or " 303 Error" Then module getting stuck and further files not uploading. if i clear the cache or relogin  in new browser then module starts working. so i believe some where some information are stored in cache and this cache is the stopper for our module. i clearly noticed this.